# Android GCM SSLException

Tags: android, exception, ssl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm planning to use GCM features for an Android app. I setup the proper Android app and the backend service deployed on localhost.

Everyting was fine and the notifications were displayed on my testing device. Next I tried to deploy the service on a different server with a real IP. Now I'm getting this strange error when I try to push the notification from the server side and I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have a solution?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
at com.gebs.floatmanagement.web.servlet.MapGenerator.sendAndroidNotification(Unknown Source)
at com.gebs.floatmanagement.web.servlet.MapGenerator.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.gebs.floatmanagement.web.servlet.MapGenerator.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:774)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:896)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: does not support java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
    at com.certicom.ecc.jcae.ECKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed on my server some applications that override some SSL features and because of those the error has raised. Removing the services or migrating the app backend service on another server solved my problems.

Comment: Finally solved it! LOL Same problem and wasted me so much time! So dumb bug. Just cause of a previous unknown web app. thx